# Is $\frac{1}{xy}\log(xya+1)$ a convex function over the domain $x, y \in (0,1], a>0$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given that $x,y \in (0,1]$ and a>0, is function $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{xy}\log(xya+1)$ a convex function?

By plotting it seems to be concave. But trying to prove analytically seems a little bit tedious. I tried to estimate its Hessian matrix and find if it is positive semi-definite but it seems too complicated, and was just a fruitless try.

By observing that $\frac{1}{xy}$, is convex, is there any easier way to find that $f$ is also convex?

Comment: A single counter example would disprove convexity.

Comment: @random, Do you have such an example? By plotting this function seems to be convex though...

Comment: $\frac 1{x^2} \log (1+x^2)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R}$ and has its maximum at $x=0$.

Comment: @random, so what does this implies for convexity of $f$?

Comment: The maximum at $x=0$ follows from a negative second derivative there and, because of its continuity, close to that point.. So $f(x,x)$ is concave for small x.